# WebAudioAPi latency on devices

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, web-audio-api

Writing because I ran into a problem using the WebAudioAPI playing buffered sample.
Basically I have a website that synchronise devices clocks, download a file on Soundcloud, and at a precise time starts playing, resulting in multiple devices playing in sync. Synchronising the clocks works well and music is played together on computers.
Trouble is, on smartphones, even though clocks are precisely synced, there seems to be a random delay, between 20ms and 500ms, and the resulting playback is not in sync..
First step towards solving the issue would be to find what is causing this delay..

I have a few idea, but no certitudes:

• Hardware latency? But then wouldn't the delay be constant?

• Too much memory usage because the buffer loading would slow things down and somehow add jitter?

Really not much clues, so even ideas of why it isn't working would be nice!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that definitely sounds like audio hardware latency.  The delay should be pretty constant on a given device and OS, but will vary widely across devices (particularly different Android devices).

We're 1) working on improving this in Android for the future, and 2) working in the spec and implementations to expose hardware latency.  For now, there's no great answer, other than keeping a table of known latencies on given devices.

Comment: Yeah I thought it should be it, but trouble is, on a given hardware, the latency does not seems to be constant. A same device could be at some time in sync, and sometimes not (ie have an audible delay). So maybe there is more to it than only hardware..

Comment: I am going to try scheduling the song playout chunk by chunk to avoid too much processor and memory usage at the start time and see if that changes something..  If not, then I guess your are right!

Comment: didn't help much! It is indeed a Hardware issue.